# Насторожённость или насторо́женность?

Tags: грамотная-речь, орфоэпия

Что правильно? Или, может быть, слова взаимозаменяемы?
В большинстве случаев букву «ё» не используют, отсюда и неразбериха.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. В словаре трудностей произношения и ударения в современном русском языке:
   [насторожённость](https://books.google.ee/books?id=2ZnOAAAAQBAJ&pg=PA274&lpg=PA274&dq=%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C%20%D0%B2%20%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B5%20%D1%83%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9&source=bl&ots=xvUvpSHniM&sig=ACfU3U1m_wOSF-Y35Ok0DGSjM0n-pymACw&hl=ru&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjezpmA1NPkAhVrkIsKHYA8A2QQ6AEwB3oECAcQAQ#v=onepage&q=%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C%20%D0%B2%20%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B5%20%D1%83%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9&f=false), -и.
   Такое же (единственное!) ударение отмечено в словаре ударений русского языка и в словаре М. В. Зарвы (Русское словесное ударение). [[см.](http://www.endic.ru/word_stress/Nastorozhennost-15591.html)]
2. Двойственное ударение показано в этих словарях.
   БТС: [насторо́женность; насторожённость](http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?word=%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE*%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9&all=x), -и; ж.
   Русский орфографический словарь: *насторожённость, -и* и *насторо́женность, -и*.
   МАС: *насторо́женность* и *насторожённость*, -и, ж.

Попытаюсь сделать вывод.
Предпочтение, думаю, надо отдать мнению специализированных словарей:
**насторожённость** — такое ударение надо считать литературным;
**насторо́женность** — так можно, допустимо говорить (ошибкой не считается).

Comment: @JailtriX Это хорошо, что Вы начали принимать ответы. Спасибо! Было бы совсем  здо́рово, если бы Вы посчитали их еще и полезными (треугольник сверху). Честно скажу — это безусловно стимулирует отвечающего.